# Можно ли автоматически отфильтровать товары при переходе в категорию по ссылке с другой страницы?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Существует div с ссылками на странице index.php:

```
<div id="categories_list_a">

        <a href="categories.php" class="livingroom_a">livingroom<img src="../images/categories/livingroom.png" id="livingroom"></a>


        <a href="categories.php" class="office_a">office<img src="../images/categories/office.png" id="office"></a>


        <a href="categories.php" class="forkids_a">for kids<img src="../images/categories/forkids.png" id="forkids"></a>


        <a href="categories.php" class="kitchen_a">kitchen<img src="../images/categories/kitchen.png" id="kitchen"></a>


        <a href="categories.php" class="accesories_a">accesories<img src="../images/categories/accesories.png" id="accesories"></a>


    <a href="categories.php" class="show_all_categories_a">show all categories</a>
    <div id="categories_stick"></div>
</div>
```

А на другой странице categories.php список кнопок

```
<div id="categories_list_cat">

        <div class="livingroom_cat" tabindex="0" data-filter="livingroom" onclick="filterSelection('livingroom')">livingroom<img src="../images/categories/livingroom.png" id="livingroom">
    </div>

    <div class="office_cat" tabindex="0" data-filter="office" onclick="filterSelection('office')">
        office<img src="../images/categories/office.png" id="office">
    </div>

    <div class="forkids_cat" tabindex="0" data-filter="forkids" onclick="filterSelection('forkids')">for kids<img src="../images/categories/forkids.png" id="forkids">
    </div>

    <div class="kitchen_cat" tabindex="0" data-filter="kitchen" onclick="filterSelection('kitchen')">kitchen<img src="../images/categories/kitchen.png" id="kitchen">
    </div>

    <div class="accesories_cat" tabindex="0" data-filter="accesories" onclick="filterSelection('accesories')">accesories<img src="../images/categories/accesories.png" id="accesories">
    </div>

<div class="show_all_categories_cat" tabindex="0" data-filter="all" onclick="filterSelection('all')">
    show all categories
    </div>

    <div id="categories_stick"></div>

    </div>
```

Возможно ли, чтобы при нажатии на ссылку с классом livingroom_a на странице index.php, происходило автоматическое нажатие на кнопку с соответствующим классом livingroom_cat на странице categories.php. И для других ссылок и кнопок соответственно. Сколько не ломал голову, ничего не получается.

Пробывал вот так:

```
$(".livingroom_a").on("click", function() {
    $(".livingroom_cat").click();
});
$(".office_a").on("click", function() {
    $(".office_cat").click();
});
$(".forkids_a").on("click", function() {
    $(".forkids_cat").click();
});
$(".kitchen_a").on("click", function() {
    $(".kitchen_cat").click();
});
$(".accesories_a").on("click", function() {
    $(".accesories_cat").click();
});
$(".show_all_categories_a").on("click", function() {
    $(".show_all_categories_cat").click();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильный вопрос: можно ли автоматически отфильтровать товары при переходе в категорию по ссылке с другой страницы?

Ответ: Да, можно.

Просто передавайте в своих ссылках через GET параметр нужный фильтр вот так:

```
<a href="categories.php?filter=kitchen" class="kitchen_a">kitchen<img src="../images/categories/kitchen.png" id="kitchen"></a>
```

А на странице categories.php проверяйте есть ли GET параметр filter и фильтруйте в момент document.ready вот так:

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['filter'])) : ?>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        filterSelection('<?php echo $_GET['filter'] ?>');
    });
<?php endif; ?>
```

Если же требуется именно эмулировать клик, то передаем значение класса кнопки, например `livingroom_cat`

И код становится таким:

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['filter'])) : ?>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $(".<?php echo $_GET['filter'] ?>").click();
    });
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: работает, спасибо. Но только тут способ без нажатия кнопки, как я понимаю. Все таки нужно, чтобы на кнопку нажималось, потому что у меня к кнопке еще одно действие привязано, а при простом переходе, оно не выполняется

Comment: Привяжите это действие к document ready если возможно. Если не возможно - перепишите фильтрацию на эмуляцию клика. Чуть позже буду у пк напишу код, если не понимаете о чем речь.

Comment: Дописал в ответ вариант с эмуляцией клика.

Comment: не получается эмулировать клик, ладно, буду искать другой способ. Спасибо :)

Comment: Все должно работать. Напишите мне в whatsapp, посмотрю ваш ресурс. +7 904 689 20 81

Comment: Эмулировать получается, если вместо $(".<?php echo $_GET['filter'] ?>").click(); пишу .livingroom_cat. При этом для других кнопок, не работает.

Comment: Посмотрите через f12 что именно вносит $_GET в эту строчку при обращении по get с другой страницы.

Comment: он вносит filter, но не кнопку, сайт на локальном сервере. Если вставляю вместо $(".<?php echo $_GET['filter'] ?>").click(); вот это $(".livingroom_cat").click(); тогда работает как надо, но только для одной категории

Comment: решил проблему, спасибо за подсказку. В filter перед названием категории поставил '.' и назвал одинаково кнопки и ссылки.

Comment: @nepotoplyaemiy Отлично. Рад что получилось помочь. Успехов! Буду благодарен за поднятие ответа вверх (я тут ради репутации)